# Is it possible to use a different Spring Batch Sequence than the default one?

Tags: java, spring-batch

In my application we have sequences as below
BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ, BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ, BATCH_JOB_SEQ.
Rather than these I want to make use of my own sequences, is it possible to do that?
Or is there a way to use separate sequences or increments?

If I change my prefix to something else then I need to change the metatables as well. I just want to change sequences but not tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rather than these I want to make use of my own sequences, is it possible to do that?

The sequences provided in the default DDLs are a starting point. You can customize them as need (start value, increment, etc). However, only the name prefix is configurable with this option.

> Or is there a way to use separate sequences or increments?

Another way is to use a custom [`DataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/support/DataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory.html) on the job repository. With this option, you have full control over the increment logic (like a custom sequence name, see javadoc of  `getIncrementer(String databaseType, String incrementerName)` method). You can find more details about this in the [Appendix A 1.4 Identity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/schema-appendix.html#metaDataIdentity) section of the reference documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I use custom the DataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory, then I need to have a custom SequenceMaxValueIncrementers well right? Wouldnt it impact all my metatables as well?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can always override [each DAO creation method](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java#L208-L242) of the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` and use the sequence you want for each entity.